# Cosmos Db library Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core (2.1.0) - Actual REST invocations

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

We are attempting to Wiremock (https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) CosmosDb invocations - so we can build integrationtests in our .net core 2.1 microservice.

By looking at the WireMock instance Request/Response entries, we can observe the following:
1) GET towards "/"

We mock the returning metadata of databases

THIS IS OK

2) GET towards collection (in our case: "/dbs/Chunker/colls/RHTMLChunks")

Returns metadata about the collections

THIS IS OK

3) POST a Query that results in one document being returned towards the documents endpoint on the collection (in our case: "/dbs/Chunker/colls/RHTMLChunks/docs")

I have tried to emulate what we get when we do the exact same query towards the CosmosDb instance in Postman, including headers and response.

However I observe that the lib does the query again, and again, and again....
(I can see this by pausing in Visual Studio, then look at the RequestLog in WireMock)

Does anyone know what should be returned. I have set up WireMock to return the following json payload:

```
{
"_rid": "q0dcAOelSAI=",
"Documents": [
    {
        "id": "gL20020621z2D34-1",
        "ChunkSize": 658212,
        "TotalChunks": 2,
        "Metadata": {
            "Active": true,
            "PublishedDate": "",
        },
        "ChunkId": 1,
        "Markup": "<h1>hello</h1>",
        "MainDestination": "gL20020621z2D34",
        "_rid": "q0dcAOelSAIHAAAAAAAAAA==",
        "_self": "dbs/q0dcAA==/colls/q0dcAOelSAI=/docs/q0dcAOelSAIHAAAAAAAAAA==/",
        "_etag": "\"0100e92a-0000-0000-0000-5ba96cf70000\"",
        "_attachments": "attachments/",
        "_ts": 1537830135
    }
],
"_count": 0
```

}

Problems:
1) Can not find .pdb belonging to Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core v2.1.0
2) What payload/headers should be returned, so the library will NOT blow up, and retry when we invoke:

```
var response = await documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<DocumentDto>(); // this hangs forever
```

Please help :)

Comment: Why not using the Azure CosmosDB emulator for local integration tests? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator

Comment: Preferably we would like to be able to test the microservice in isolation, however if this proves to hard, then using the emulator is a decent fallback solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're working on open sourcing the C# code base and some other fun improvements to make this easier. In the mean time, I'd advocate for using the emulator for local testing/etc., although I understand mocking is still a lot faster an nicer - it'll just be hard :)

My best pointer is actually our Node.js code base since that's public already. The query code is relatively hard to follow, but basically, you create a query, we look up all the partitions we need to talk to, then we send a request for each partition and keep querying until we don't get back a continuation token anymore (or maxBufferedItem Count/etc. goes over the limit, and we pause until goes back down, etc.)

Effectively, we send out N number of requests for each partition, where N is the number of pages of results, and can vary per partition and query. You'd likely be able to mock a single partition, single page response relatively easy, but a full partition response isn't gonna be fun.

As I mentioned in the beginning, we've got some cool stuff coming, hopefully before the end of the year, which will make offline mocking easier, as well as open sourcing it finally. You might be better off with the emulator until then.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. Looking forward to the opensourcening of the C# library . If you are able to make the library WireMockable, that would be awesome (or easily testable within the application itself)!

Comment: We're planning (just planning, could change :)) to basically borrow the HttpClient delegate handler pipeline. With that, it makes it really simple to drop in a mocker without worrying too much about the wire part. We might even have a library to make that easy.

Comment: By making it easy to do in-solution integration style testing would give cosmos db a huge tech selling point - at least in my book. Let me know if you need alpha/beta testers :)